# Lumen check database configured without prompting error

Tags: php, lumen

My lumen application is connecting to multiple databases, one of my function need to connect to the database by URL parameter, is there any way to check the database already exists in my `config/database.php`?

I've tried to use the function below :

```
$client = $request->input('client');
if (!$databse->setConnection($client)->getDatabaseName()) {
    return 'no db';
}
```

but if the database not exists it will prompt error, even I can catch `InvalidArgumentException` to display the error message, but is there any alternative way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `has` method from the `Config` facade to check if the connection is configured:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;

...

if(Config::has('database.connections.client_connection')) {
  echo "The database exists.";
} else {
  echo "Please create the database first!";
}
```